# Combine sum and multiply functions

Tags: swift

I created two functions in **Swift**, one for **multiplication** and one for **addition**:
Only difference between these two functions is operator used in reduce **+** and *

```
func multiply(_ values: [Any?]) -> Double {
  return values.filter({
    $0 is Numeric
  })
  .map({
    ($0 as? any Numeric)?.doubleValue
  })
  .reduce(0) {
    $0 * ($1?.doubleValue ?? 0)
  }
}

func sum(_ values: [Any?]) -> Double {
  return values.filter({
    $0 is Numeric
  })
  .map({
    ($0 as? any Numeric)?.doubleValue
  })
  .reduce(0) {
    $0 + ($1?.doubleValue ?? 0)
  }
}

protocol Numeric {
  var doubleValue: Double {
    get
  }
}

extension Double: Numeric {
  var doubleValue: Double {
    return self
  }
}

extension Int: Numeric {
  var doubleValue: Double {
    return Double(self)
  }
}

extension String: Numeric {
  var doubleValue: Double {
    return Double(self.filter("0123456789.".contains)) ?? 0.0
  }
}
```

How to **combine** these two functions into one function?
Any idea using **Generics** instead of `Any`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all your `multiply` function cannot work because the initial value of `reduce` is zero and the result of multiplication by zero is zero.

It's not possible with generics because both `reduce` functions require a different default value apart from the operator.

You could add a parameter `operator` and `switch` on it to execute the proper `reduce` version. The `doubleValue` of `String` causes the same problem in the multiplication operation. The solution is to return an optional `Double` and filter the *bad* values  with `compactMap`.

Another problem is that the protocol `Numeric` already exists in the Standard Library. This is my suggestion:

```
enum Operator { case sum, multiply }

func calculate(_ values: [Any?], op: Operator) -> Double {
    let mappedValues = values.compactMap{ ($0 as? MyNumeric)?.doubleValue }
    switch op {
        case .sum:
            return mappedValues.reduce(0.0, +)
        case .multiply:
            return mappedValues.reduce(1.0, *)
    }
}

protocol MyNumeric {
  var doubleValue: Double? { get }
}

extension Double: MyNumeric {
  var doubleValue: Double? { return self }
}

extension Int: MyNumeric {
  var doubleValue: Double? { return Double(self) }
}

extension String: MyNumeric {
  var doubleValue: Double? { return Double(self.filter("0123456789.".contains)) }
}

let array : [Any?] = [1, 2, "3", 4.0, 5]
let multi = calculate(array, op: .multiply)
let sum = calculate(array, op: .sum)
print(sum, multi)
```